# Python unitest doesn't run test functions from PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, pythonanywhere

I'm having a problem with unittest testing, code and results below.

I try to run my test from the PythonAnywhere IDE, and it says that 0 test has been made.

I tested the code with prints to find out where things went wrong and I found out that interpreter doesn't even go into the function to see the test.
I know the test names should start with "test_", which they do.
Any other idea?

I am working on pythonAnywhere if it's matter somehow.

My code:

```py
import unittest
import signUpForm

class Test_signUp(unittest.TestCase):

    print ("i got to here")
    def test_Utility(self):
        print ("but never here")
        # test all utlity functions in the sign up form. and delete the changes afterward
        #check system addition and manipulation
        self.assertEqual(addSystem ("dungeons" , 8000) , "added dungeons to systems list")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(exit = False)
```

When I run this I get:

```
i got to here
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK
>>>
```

Comment: How are you running your tests? Placing your snippet into a file named `code.py` and running `python3 -m unittest code.py` seems to test the `test_Utility` method just fine.

Comment: i am using the run envirment of pythonanywhere.
that really good to know that its run fine in a shell. the problem is i need it to run in pythonAnywehere

Comment: hey - i do have a bash console in there, and i tried running it there and it worked!
so first of all - THANK YOU! i am lost for 3 days on this problem.

is there a way to make it run fine in the  IDE?

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with pythonAnywhere. But I do know that tests may run or not depending on your environment setup, which is why I asked how you were running them.

Comment: well, thanks you very much! i can work with the console and move on.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the IDE in PythonAnywhere -- the easiest workaround would be to close the console in the editor (using `exit()`, then refresh the page, and start a new console using the "Bash console here" button that will appear where the old console was.  Then you can use the command that @jfaccioni suggested there, but have your test results on the same browser tab as your editor.

Comment: hey, thank a lot. you are right, that what i figured out when @jfaccioni told me it worked for him. if you want to add your answer as an answer I'll mark it as the right one

Comment: Sure!  I've done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a bug in the IDE in PythonAnywhere -- the easiest workaround would be to close the console in the editor (using `exit()`), then refresh the page, and start a new console using the "Bash console here" button that will appear where the old console was. Then you can use the command that @jfaccioni suggested in the comments to your question:

```
python3 -m unittest code.py
```

...but have your test results on the same browser tab as your editor.